# What's the difference between "to ratify" and "to sign"?

Tags: synonyms

I came across these sentences at Aljazeera English "Only four countries have not signed or ratified the convention. They include: Egypt, South Sudan, North Korea and Israel (signed but not ratified)."
I want to know what is the difference between "to ratify" and "to sign", especially in the sentence in parentheses?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124005/discussion-on-question-by-sina-rahimi-whats-the-difference-between-to-ratify).